# Why does this javascript regex give me a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use this regexp from [jeff Atwood's blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html) on detecting links:

```
\(?\bhttp://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]
```

However, this JS code breaks and gives a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

```
var myRe = \(?\bhttp://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|];
var myArray = myRe.exec("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_Tools_(Central_Point_Software)");
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: As an aside comment, you can reduce the size of your character classes using ranges and `\w`: `var myRe = /\(?\bhttp:\/\/[!#%&()+-;=?-Z_a-z~|]*[-\w#%&()+\/=@|~]/;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your JS is in fact invalid. This is not a valid RegExp literal:

```
var myRe = \(?\bhttp://[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|];
```

A RegExp literal starts with `/` and similarly ends with `/` in JS, so you can change the code to this:

```
var myRe = /\(?\bhttp:\/\/[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_()|]/;
```

And it [should work](http://jsbin.com/iZaKIror/1/edit) (you may need to turn on the console tab.) Note that because `/` is a literal terminal, you have to escape any `/` characters in your RegExp with a `\` character.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring it as a regex variable (inside //):

```
var myRe = /\(?\bhttp:\/\/[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]/;
```

And check out [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp).

Comment: Please don’t use `new RegExp`. (e.g. you forgot to escape `\b`)

Comment: Yeah, I'll get rid of the dysfunctional first one. Second one's fine.